# Make Child DIv remain Fixed while Horizontal Scrolling Parent Div

Tags: css, html, scroll

I have a parent div with over flow and hence horizontal scroll,
This holds a grid and some data the paging controls for this lies in in another div below it

problem is i want the paging div to be fixed even when parent div is scrolled(only x scroll)

```
<div style="overflow:scroll">
<table>data</table>
<div id="bottom">Paging</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant CSS for these elements? And provide a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Finally, have you tried `position: fixed;`?

Comment: my page also has scroll vertical , position fixed will keep it on the page all the time which beats my purpose

Comment: Then it'll need to be a JavaScript solution, I'd imagine.

Comment: if you want to make #bottom at fixed position then why to include it into `<div style="overflow:scroll">`?

Comment: can u suggest me a js solution for this?

Comment: the data table nested within the parent has a lot of columns and the overflow only on table was not restricting its x-length,overflow on parent solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options:

1. place your pagination object [outside the scrollable element](http://jsfiddle.net/ppzCA/2/)
2. use `position:fixed;`. Note however, that an element with fixed position is positioned according to the browser-viewport and not the parent-element. This means, you have to know the dimensions of your elements to place the pager in the right position.

edit:
[Fiddle for fixed position](http://jsfiddle.net/ppzCA/1/)

Comment: my page has a vertical scroll and makin position fixed will keep it fixed all the time rite?? i want it fixed only wrt the parent.

Comment: the child div is auto generated from datatable.js so i cant place it outside the parent

Comment: @czar41 In this case you won't be able to tackle the problem without javascript.

Comment: i have the class for the child div its #bottom cant i set left margin on scroll of parent not sure how to do this but is that not possible?

Comment: @czar41 fyi `#bottom` is an `id`, not a `class`. What do you want to achieve with `margins`? They generate space outside of the element, you can't use it, to shift child elements outside the container, especially with overflow declared.

Comment: i resolved the issue here is what i did...i put the child div outside parent using jqery.....parentdiv=$('.bottom').parent(); parentdiv.append($('.bottom'))...... the power and simplicity of jqery constantly amazes me.... thank you all for the help

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is just to take the bottom div out of the container. Does this div have to be inside the container?

http://jsfiddle.net/ollie/rTjB3/

Comment: the div is auto generated datatable.js but i can control it by its class

Answer (score 0):

**fixed div in scrollable div**

```
#container {
    position:absolute;
     top:150px;
    left:150px;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
     border:3px dashed #ffff00;
     padding:0px;
    }

#this_scroll {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:99%;
    height:99%;
    overflow:scroll;
    border:2px solid #000;
    margin:1px;
    background:#B0BDCE;
    }

#close {
     position:absolute;
    top:2px;
     right:21px;
    width:90px;
    height:30px;
    overflow:none;
    border:2px solid #660099;
    z-index:10;
    background:#8C8C8C;
    }



<div id="container">

    <div id="this_scroll">
    <p> some </p> <p> some </p> <p> some </p>
    </div>

    <div id="close">
        close
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Instead of posting just CSS, you might want to explain how it should work.